# MacOS Finder Extension does not delete with the application

Tags: macos, cocoa, finder, finder-extension

I am using Finder Extension in my app, it works perfectly. But once user uninstalls the app, he is still able to see the overlays on Finder items.

I googled and found the same issue exists for Dropbox as well, user has to manually unlink the Finder Extension.

[image]

Is there any better way to achieve this?